# Safari cuts off box-shadow of element inside button

Tags: css, safari, box-shadow

I have a button with an element inside it that receives box-shadow:

```css
button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: white;
}

.shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #dddddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="shadow"></span>
  <span>Some Text</span>
</button>
```

In Safari, this shadow gets cut off at the edge of the `<button>` element and looks like this:

[image: Button with inner box-shadow cut off in Safari]

As you can see I tried `-webkit-appearance: none` and `overflow: visible` already. I've also found that this issue does not occur if I change the button to a div, but this is meant to be an interactive element so for accessibility reasons it's not a good idea.

In searching for this issue I haven't found much help so far but I'm wondering if anyone might know of any recent workarounds or Safari CSS hacks that could help with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some more searching (for non-box-shadow-related clipping on buttons in Safari) and found a simple solution.

Adding `position: relative` to `.shadow` lets the element extend beyond the bounds of the `<button>` tag in Safari. It sounds like this would also work for text overflowing and such.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you!!
do you have a link to the explanation why this happened?

Comment: I don't think I found a specific explanation, just other stackoverflow posts about other issues that I thought I'd try to see if they worked. Seems like Safari just doesn't do overflow correctly on buttons